# Math formula for positioning a box relative to where the user clicked within constraints?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

This is going to be difficult for me to explain but I'm looking for a mathematical formula which defines the position a box pops out relative to where the user clicked in a column of rows.

Here's an attempt at articulating what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f73ST.jpg

The red circle is where the user clicks in the column on the left and the box on the right is what pops out. So when the user clicks a row at the bottom of the column the box should pop out so the bottom edge is lined up to the bottom of the column. If the user clicks in the middle it should be aligned to the middle. This is so the box that pops out never runs past the height of the column on the left so the user never has to scroll.

Does that make sense? I can use CSS to set the absolute position of the box but I just need a formula to work out where it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's one formula that will satisfy this condition, but with some programming you can get it working. You start with the obvious:

```
top    := click.y - height / 2
bottom := click.y + height / 2
```

Then you refine it:

```
if bottom > container.height -> 
    bottom := container.height
    top    := MAX(0, bottom - height)
elif top < 0 ->
    top    := 0
    bottom := MIN(container.height, height)
fi
```

Comment: This effectively achieves what I want, but I was thinking of something cooler where the position of the box on the right is always lined up to the equivalent position clicked on the left even if it doesn't run over. I can't explain this well at all...

Comment: @Pancakes This pseudo code would line it up, based on the vertical centre position like how you drew it.

Comment: Oh hold in, now I feel stupid. I was completely over complicating what is really a pretty simple solution. Your solution does exactly what I want lol what was I even thinking. Thanks!